# Given a contact in my Google Contact app, how can I see where it is stored? (which Google account? SIM card? phone internal memory? etc.)

Tags: contacts, android-12, google-pixel-6

Given a contact in my Google Contact app, how can I see where it is stored (which Google account? SIM card? phone internal memory? etc.)

I use a Pixel 6 and Android 12.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a built-in way on Android.  You may like to try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contacts.smartcontacts.Contact). I haven't used it